# Intra-EU freelancer / contractor invoicing rules (taxes)

Tags: taxes, invoices, eu

I have a very specific question about invoicing a company in another EU country. The circumstances are as follows:

1. I live in country A.
2. The Company being invoiced resides in country B.
3. I have a bank account in country B.
4. I am a part-time employer (employed in country A).
5. I want to invoice the Company in country's B currency (money would be then transferred to my bank account in country B).
6. I want to pay taxes related to these invoices in country A.

Is that generally accepted pattern / scenario? Does that mean the invoice should include VAT? If so, which country's tax rate should I use?

Comment: I would talk to an accountant, but I don't see why that would be an issue. Just go and declare your earnings to your local financial institution. You might have to move the money in country A though. Being in the EU means you can pretty much open an account in any EU currency depending on your local banks so with that consideration in mind I think you can declare revenue in any currency

Answer (score 3):

I used to do the same thing (Part-time employed in country A, as well as self-employed invoicing other clients in country B in a different currency), so I'll tell you what I did.

1. Create a **self-employed company in country A**
2. Create a **bank account in country A - with currency of country B**, and link that account to your self-employed company
3. Ask your **Revenue office** (from country A) **to issue you a** **[VIES number](https://europa.eu/youreurope/business/vat-customs/check-number-vies/index_en.htm)**. In this case you'll be allowed to invoice any company in EU, and shouldn't be worried about VAT.

After all that you should pay tax to the Revenue office from country A according to country A regulations.

> I want to invoice the Company in country's B currency (money would be
>   then transferred to my bank account in country B).

As far as I know that's only possible if you create a self-employed company in country B.

**NOTE** 
Please be advised that I'm not an accountant or a lawyer, for a specialized answer contact your local Revenue office.